# about unrecognised flag error in haskell when compile

Tags: haskell, gtk3

I want to ask that i can run these two commands properly without error but I can't put them together to compile the program in Haskell.

This is the two lines I have run

```bash
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

return the result

```
-DLIBDEFLATE_DLL -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/webp -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/include
```

and the other

```bash
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

return the result

```
-LC:/tools/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lhid -lwinspool -lcomctl32 -lcomdlg32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

The command I want to run is:

```bash
ghc -o t t.hs `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

it returns:

```
ghc-9.6.1.exe: unrecognised flag: --cflags
unrecognised flag: --libs

Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

Comment: 1. Why do you try to pass `CFLAGS` to a non C compiler, 2. *If* that's valid why don't you combine them `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`? 3. Have you tried other forms of command substitution, i.e. in bash or zsh or similar `ghc -o t t.hs $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)`? What shell are you running anyways?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
1. I have try various thing to compile the program but seem no result so I tried to passed like that with the cflags with hope.
2.I don't know this method until you show me. Thank you.
3. Yes, but they didn't work too, with yours show me, the result still unrecognised flags: --libs

Comment: I see you might be on Windows because `ghc-9.6.1.exe` looks like a Windows executable name. Perhaps you are using some shell that is not bash or similar. Backticks only works on those. They do not work, or work in  a very different way, on Windows shells such as cmd or powershell. Use bash. (If you get it right, you end up getting `ghc: unrecognised flag: -pthread`, which is a genuine problem you will need to solve).